# What does 何があんだよ mean here?

Tags: meaning, translation, sentence

> なんでここに?

Why are you here

> 飯食いに来た以外に何があんだよ

"Other than coming to eat..."

I'm stumbled on this meaning of 何があんだよ. From context he seems to be saying "what else is there to do here?"

However would  he use か if it was a question? What is this meaning of 何があんだよ?

Comment: Would it be clearer to you if it was written out in full as 何があるのだよ? You've got ghe gist of the meaning. Also, questions don't absolutely require using か and can be expressed through intonation.

Comment: Did you copy it correctly? I believe も is not there.

Answer (score 1):

何があんだよ is short for 何があるんだよ, where ん is an explanatory-の and よ is a sentence-end particle. For the underlying rules of this contraction, see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010).

For this だ, see [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55641/5010). When in speech, it works as a masculine and rough question marker. 何があるのか would be grammatically correct, too, but it sounds stilted and formal, making it almost impossible in an informal conversation like this.